# Function in a thread python while true and return True

Tags: python, multithreading

```
def is_file_loaded():
    while not has_active_popup():
        continue
    return True

def load_example_file(config):  
    popup_thread = threading.Thread(target=is_file_loaded(), args='')
    popup_thread.start()

    popup_thread.join(timeout=10.0)
    client.load_file(config_filepath)
    # This is a blocking call because there is a popup and 
    # it does not return a value until I close the popup (Blocking Popup)

    do_thing_one()
    do_thing_two()
    return True
```

I would like that when I start the thread, it's going to run for a maximum of 10 seconds. If it returns True then I will execute

```
    do_thing_one()
    do_thing_two()
    return True
```

Right now what is happening is that :

client.load_file is called but do not returns until the popup is closed.

I need to detect that there is a popup in another thread so I can close it , kill the thread and resume the execution of the function

Comment: A better explanation of what is working/current status and what is the expected result would help understand the problem more.

Comment: you might need to check is_alive() on the thread object,
From the python Threading link: 
When the timeout argument is present and not None, it should be a floating point number specifying a timeout for the operation in seconds (or fractions thereof). As join() always returns None, you must call is_alive() after join() to decide whether a timeout happened – if the thread is still alive, the join() call timed out.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.isAlive

if you want the thread to timeout you need to need to have a timeout mechanism in the thread.